# How to insert data in mysql from another table and local variables in asp.net

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I want to add lotno,date,catid,rcno from a table lot and local c# variables buyid,prc,datetime, all to the table soldlot. How do I do this?  Im using MySql.

```
string datetime = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"); 
String q6 = "insert into soldlot (lotNo,date,categoryId,receiptNo) (select @lotno,date,@catid,@rcno from lot)";
MySqlCommand c6 = new MySqlCommand(q6, cn);
c6.Parameters.Add("@lotno",lotno);
c6.Parameters.Add("@catid",catid);
c6.Parameters.Add("@buyerId", buyid);
c6.Parameters.Add("@rcno", rcno);                    
c6.Parameters.Add("@soldPrice", prc);
c6.Parameters.Add("@soldDate", datetime);
c6.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: You get any exception or error message? What is wrong exactly? And don't store your `DateTime` as a `string`.

Comment: But I want to insert the values from another table and the local values in the c# code too. Please guide me as to how to go about it? I dont know how to add buyerId,soldPrice and soldDate to the query.(they are local variables)

Comment: How do I store the Date so as to get it in the format "yyyy-MM-dd"?

Comment: @anasmilas getting off-topic, but you don't need to store it in a particular format, its just stored as a date (technically a number internally I think). Format it with c# when you want to display it on a UI

Answer (score 0):

When you say;

```
select @lotno,date,@catid,@rcno from lot
```

You try to parameterize your column names, **not your values**.

You need to use them like;

```
select lotno, date, catid, rcno from lot
where lotno = @lotno and date = @date and catid = @catid and rcno = @rcno
```

Read [13.2.5 INSERT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html)

And looks like you don't need `@buyerId`, `@soldPrice` and `@soldDate` because you didn't even define them in your command.

If you wanna save your `DateTime` values, don't store in any character typed column. Use `datetime` or relevant type and pass your `DateTime` values directly to your [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/).

Also use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your database connections and objects as well.

Comment: I dint know how to add them in the command. Please tell me how to do so?

Comment: @anasmilas You already adding your local variables as a parameter with `.Add()` method. But your `INSERT` statement syntax is wrong. You need add your parameter values in your values part, not your column names. That's why you can't say like `select @lotno,date,@catid,@rcno from lot`

Comment: Ive used the 'using' statement. How do I add sysdate(soldDate),buyerid and soldprice in the query?

Comment: Ok,I got that. How do I add the values soldDate(sysdate),buyerId and soldPrice,which are local variables(they are not coming from any table). How do I add them as well along with lotno,date,catid,rcno to the soldlot table. How to save date from mysql in asp.net? Im not being able to do the casting.

Comment: @anasmilas [`SYSDATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sysdate) doesn't take any parameter. What do you mean by `sysdate(soldDate)`? And if you want to use `@buyerid` and `@soldprice` parameter values, you need to declare them in your command as you did for other parameters.

Comment: I want to add sysdate to the column soldDate in the table soldlot. Thats exactly what Im asking, how do I declare them in the command?

Comment: @anasmilas `SYSDATE` returns the current date and time. Do you need add this to `soldDate` column for all row that you inserted?

Comment: Yes,just the current date,not the time.